# \n in python is not getting a new line

Tags: python

In my python script I ma sending mail and for that I am using `\n` for the line break but instead of a next line it just vanishes from the output mail, I don't under stand why this is happening.

For e.g

```
"Dear Sir, \n Please note we have received short material against return docket {} on {} from {}". format(a,b,c)
```

Output:

```
Dear Sir, Please note we have received short material against...
```

Comment: What tool are you using? Please provide a [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's important to see what kind of text format it expects.

Comment: Try using `\r\n`, as far as I remember plain-text email requires CRLF for line breaking. If you're writing an HTML mail, use `<br>`.

Comment: Your email client usually translates between local line-ending conventions and whatever SMTP requires.

Comment: @tripleee Maybe their python script _is_ the email client.

Comment: Yeah, so `smtplib` will take care of the conversion if necessary, or `sendmail` if they end up using that to get the message off the system.

Answer (score 1):

Use [<br/>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) instead of `\n`. HTML collapses more than one white space and renders it as single space.